# i am migrating my code from vb6 to vb.net 2012.what is the eqvivalent of BaseDataEnvironement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

this is the warning i am getting
'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.BaseDataEnvironment' is obsolete: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.* classes are obsolete and supported within 32 bit processes only.

Answer (score 0):

There's no single replacement. You have to give code listings and ask for help in each separate case.